# How to get a number from a class name in jquery?

Tags: jquery, regex, match

I tried several solutions but the code still doesn't work...

Here is what I got so far:

```
$('.next-arrow').click(function (){
    var num = $(this).closest('[class^=step-]').match(/\d+/)[0];
    console.log(num);
});
```

If I run it without the `.match()` it works fine and tells me that I'm at "step-1" on console log, but adding .match() doesn't return anything.

What I'm trying to do here is to check where I'm at "step-1, step-2,..." and assign that number to hide the currently step and show the next step.

Comment: jQuery objects do not have a `match()` method.

Comment: Parsing the class name is not the right approach. Use the index of the element, or use DOM traversal to show and hide elements based on their relative positions.

Comment: As a side note, you could achieve this a bit more elegantly by using `data` attributes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to take a class of the found element instead of the element itself:

```
$('.next-arrow').click(function (){
    var num = $(this).closest('[class^=step-]').attr("class").match(/\d+/)[0];
    console.log(num);
});
```

Comment: @William then you might want to accept the answer rather than keeping this hanging!

Comment: @Chaitanya Gadkari, I will do that, I'm only waiting the cool down time from stackoverflow, thanks!